# How do you calculate a total when line have multiple quantities in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a function for SQL Sever that will calculate the total price of an order. This is easily said and done, but the problem is that instead of the order having multiple lines for each item, it uses a UnitsOrdered field that stores the quantity.

The image below shows the three line items of an order and the fields I'm discussing.

[image]

The outcome I'm looking for is the following:

| RetailUnitPrice | UnitsOrderd | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 485.41 | 1 | 485.41 |
| 252.30 | 1 | 252.30 |
| 25.91 | 2 | 51.82 |
|  | **Grand Total:** | **789.53** |
|  |  |  |

Creating a query that can get the total of lines with more than 1 item has been my challenge.

The below examples are different pieces of code that I tried.

```
Alter Function fn_CalculatePTPrice
  (@psPickTicket   TPickTicketNo)
  -------------------------------
  Returns TFloat
As 
Begin
  Declare
    @ftotalPrice       TFloat;
    @iReturn           TFloat;

    SELECT @fTotalPrice = ISNULL((
      SELECT SUM(P.RetailUnitPrice * P.UnitsOrdered)
      from tblPickTicketDtl P
      join tblCase C on (P.PickTicketNo = C.PickTicketNo)
      where P.PickTicketNo = @psPickTcket
      ), 0);

    set @iReturn = @fTotalPrice;
    _Return:
  Return(@iReturn);
End /* fn_CalculatePTPrice */
```

and this

```
ALTER Function fn_CalculatePTPrice
  (@psPickTicket   TPickTicketNo)
  -------------------------------
  Returns TFloat
As 
Begin
  Declare
    @iReturn           TFloat,
    @iTotalLineNumbers TInteger,
    @iIndex            TInteger,
    @fTotalPrice       TFloat;

    set @iIndex = 1;
    set @iTotalLineNumbers = (ISNULL((select top 1 PickLineNo
                             from tblPickTicketDtl
                             where PickTicketNo = @psPickTicket
                             order by PickLineNo desc), 0))

    while(@iIndex <= @iTotalLineNumbers)
      BEGIN

        set @fTotalPrice += (ISNULL((select  SUM(P.RetailUnitPrice*P.UnitsOrdered)
                        from tblPickTicketDtl P
                        left outer join tblCase C on (P.PickTicketNo = C.PickTicketNo)
                        where P.PickTicketNo = @psPickTicket
                        and P.PickLineNo = @iIndex), 0))
        set @iIndex += 1;
      END

    set @iReturn = @fTotalPrice;

    _Return:
  Return(@iReturn);
End /* fn_CalculatePTPrice */
```

At this point I'm not really sure what to try next, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

My company uses User-Defined Data Types in our database, so TInteger = Integer, TFloat = Float, and TPickTicketNo = varchar(30)

Comment: I would strongly suggest rethinking *both* of those function, they are both scalar functions. The first *might* be able to able to be inlined in SQL Server 2019, however, the latter will certainly not be able to, *and* it contains a `WHILE`; it'll perform terribly. You really need to be writing inline table value function if you want performant solutions.

Comment: What are the data types `TFloat` and `TInteger` and `TPickTicketNo`? None of these are built in Data types.

Comment: TInteger  = integer
TFLoat    = float
TPickTicket = varchar(30)

Comment: As for the problem, why are you not just doing `RetailUnitPrice * UnitsOrderd`?

Comment: *"TInteger = integer"* so why not use `integer`? Is `TInteger` an alias data type? I would strongly urge you not use those.

Comment: My company uses our own naming convention and we have created our own data types for easy in programming.

Comment: If you *ever* need to change the data types (for example, `TPickTicket` needs to be 35 characters long), you are in for a world of pain and suffering.

Comment: I use ```RetailUnitPrice * UnitsOrderd``` in the first function example, and it was way off when I ran it through

Comment: We have a document that we can use to update the database as we need, so it's easy to make changes.

Comment: Because you're returning a `TInteger` which I *assume* is returns an integer like value. Your expected values, such as `51.82`, are clearly *not* integers, they are decimal values.

Comment: I wouldn't say creating creating a new column for *every* column that exists with the old alias type, updating all those columns with the value of the old alias type, dropping all the constraints, keys, and indexes for the old alias type columns, then dropping the old columns and alias type, recreating the alias type with the correct definition, recreated the columns with the new alias type, updating the new columns with the value of the prior "new" columns value, then recreating all your constraints, keys and indexes and dropping the "new" interim columns "easy".

Comment: I'm doing the math as TFloat and then returning TInteger. I believe this is sufficient to cast the float to an int. Since you point it out, I should be returning a float.

Comment: Please show sample data for both tables, and expected results. I'm pretty certain the problem lies in the way you're calculating iTotalLineNumbers.
But I agree with Larnu that re-designing the function would make _much_ more sense.

Comment: @JacobNorth  YOur understanding is flawed. `51.82` as an `int` is `51`; hence why you get the wrong result. You don't need a function to do `RetailUnitPrice * UnitsOrderd` anyway. Just put the expression in your `SELECT`. This, in truth, has a very very *very* strong smell of a considerably over complicated design. It's like you're treating SQL like it's C# and defining a function and class for *everything*. Don't, just don't...

Comment: I know that casting to an int is going to drop the decimal. The error I'm talking about is hundreds of dollars off on the calculation. This means regardless of me casting to an int, the function is production the wrong result.

I'm going to change the return to a float, but that won't help the issue.

Comment: SQL provides language elements to encourage set-based programming. The interpreter will get the best performance if you use them. If you start introducing functions where they are not needed, performance will suffer.

Comment: @JacobNorth Don't use FLOAT or REAL for money.  You don't wish to deal with sneaky rounding errors. More [here](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-dangers-of-using-float-or-real-datatypes). Rather use DECIMAL or MONEY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: Via @Charlieface who pointed out that the below code would aggregate the rows when using `SUM`

I found a better way of handling this issue.

I'm going to use the following:

```
select SUM(UnitsOrdered * RetailUnitPrice) as TotalPrice
from tblPickTicketDtl
where PickTicketNo = @psPickTicket
```

This gives me the result I'm looking for. I'm not a pro at SQL so if you see any improvements please let me know.

Comment: What's the point of the subquery? If you have no `GROUP BY` then you anyway only have one row, so no need to sum again

Comment: The table that is being returned has N number of rows based on how many lines there is on the specific order. In the table above you can see the multiple lines that will be returned for the ```TotalPrice``` field. So to get the sum of all the lines I sum one more time to get the total.

Comment: The `SUM` forces the rows to be aggregated. You could only get multiple row if you have a `GROUP BY` clause, which you do not

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, you're right, I blew that too.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (OrderID int, RetailUnitPrice float, UnitsOrdered int);

INSERT INTO orders (OrderID,RetailUnitPrice,UnitsOrdered)
VALUES (1,485.41,1),(1,252.3,1),(1,25.91,2),(2,485.41*0.5,1),(2,252.3*0.75,1),(2,25.91*4,2);
```

Return line items and order totals in-line:

```
SELECT OrderID, RetailUnitPrice, UnitsOrdered, SUM(RetailUnitPrice*UnitsOrdered) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID) AS OrderTotal
FROM orders;
```

Return line items and order sub-totals:

```
SELECT OrderID
, CASE WHEN GROUPING(RetailUnitPrice) = 1 THEN 'Total for OrderID ' + CAST(OrderID AS nvarchar(10)) ELSE CAST(RetailUnitPrice AS nvarchar(10)) END AS RetailUnitPrice
, CASE WHEN GROUPING(UnitsOrdered) = 1 THEN 'Total for OrderID ' + CAST(OrderID AS nvarchar(10)) ELSE CAST(UnitsOrdered AS nvarchar(10)) END AS UnitsOrdered
, SUM(RetailUnitPrice*UnitsOrdered) AS Total
FROM orders
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((OrderId,RetailUnitPrice,UnitsOrdered),(OrderId))
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ee8986f28ed3e9bab86bdf57cf1ff1d)